# Using SVN in Xamarin Studio on Mac

Tags: macos, svn, xamarin, version-control, xamarin-studio

I'd like to use SVN for my new project in Xamarin Studio on macOS Sierra, but when I want to select a repository all I get is Git. I thought Xamarin Studio supports both Git and SVN out of the box. Is there something I need to install?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If are using the most recent version of Xamarin Studio (Version 6.2 build 1821) there are issues depending upon what Subversion/svn is installed on your Mac.

- Help / Open Log Directory
- Find the most recent `Ide.XXXXX.log` (i.e. `Ide.2017-03-01__06-09-02.log`)
- Review the log for references to `Subversion`, you just might find the following warning:

  **WARNING [2017-03-01 06:09:39Z]: Subversion addin could not load libsvn_client, so it will be disabled.**

If so, file a bug @ https://bugzilla.xamarin.com and use `svn` from the cmd line or a 3rd-party SVN GUI client...

Note: I know that having svn v1.9.5_1 installed will cause the most recent Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio for Mac versions to fault on **any** solution/project loading (even if they do not use SVN) and require the SubVersion AddIn to be disabled (via the `Add-in Manager` (or `Extensions` on Visual Studio for Mac).

```
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix.LibApr0.apr_pool_create_ex (intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0000c] in <ec614fb9e74e466baa337de36616d378>:0
  at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix.LibApr0.pool_create_ex (intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4010/d41b6e51/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix/LibApr.cs:104
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. from [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89566/svn-not-working-on-latest-version-of-xs-6-2)

```
ln -s "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/" "/var/db/xcode_select_link"
```

Xcode 8.3.2 and Xamarin 6.3 Build 863

Answer (score 0):

As Xamarin 6.3 is the final "real" Xamarin version (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.3/xamarin.studio_6.3/)), I assume MS removed the svn capability in order to direct people to Visual Studio for Mac which is the successor of Xamarin: [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/de/vs/visual-studio-mac/). VS for Mac supports Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem when I only install XCode but did not install Xcode Command Line Tool.

Subversion appear in version control type dropdown after I install it.

> xcode-select --install